# opening db connection using rest webservices and getting data from db

Tags: java, rest

I want to know how can I pass a parameter to the Rest url and use that parameter to get data from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use query param to pass the parameter and than process it i am giving u a very simple hints.

```
@GET
@Produces( { "application/xml", "application/json" })
@Path("getDataFromDB")
public ResponseConverter getDataFromDB(
        @QueryParam("recordId") Integer recordId) {
```

// process with recordId.

}

It will work for you if any doubts let me know.

Comment: can you give me an example for this

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can extract parameters from request in Jersey:
http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e253

Answer (score 0):

try to read this link, its very usefull and also have the example with source code and jars, it will take little time to read but you will get your answer.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html

Answer (score 0):

You can send the JDBC properties in matrix parameters or request parameters. But this practice is very unrecommended.

By doing this you will become venerable in leaking out your info. But for beginner you can do this.

Example:

```
@Path("connect")
public class DBResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/{url}/{port}/{userId}/{password}")
    public void getConnection(@PathParam("url") String url,
                        @PathParam("port") String port,
                        @PathParam("userId") String userId,
                        @MatrixParam("password") String password) {
    ... // make the connection string
    }
}
```